# The model.predict(),model.predict_classes() and model.predict_on_batch() seems to produce no result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created a model that makes use of deep learning to classify the input data using CNN. The classification is multi-class though, actually with 5 classes. On training the model seems to be fine, i.e. it doesn't overfit or underfit. Yet, on saving and loading the model I always get the same output regardless of the input image. The final prediction array contains the output as 0 for all the classes.

So, I am not sure if the model doesn't predict anything or it always produces the same result.

The model created by me after using tensorboard to find the best fit model is below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time

X=pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
y=pickle.load(open("y.pickle","rb"))

X=X/255.0

dense_layers=[0]
layer_sizes=[64]
conv_layers=[3]


for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            NAME="{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer,layer_size,dense_layer,int(time.time()))
            print(NAME)

            tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir='logs\{}'.format(NAME))

            model = Sequential()

            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

            for l in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3)))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

            model.add(Flatten())

            for l in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))

            model.add(Dense(5))
            model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

            model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                         optimizer='adam',
                         metrics=['accuracy'])

            model.fit(X,y,batch_size=32,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3,callbacks=[tensorboard])

model.save('0x64x3-CNN-latest.model')
```

The loading model snippet is as below,

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES= ["fifty","hundred","ten","thousand","twenty"]

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE=100
    img_array=cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array=cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)

model=tf.keras.models.load_model("0x64x3-CNN-latest.model")

prediction=model.predict([prepare('30.jpg')])

print(prediction)
```

The output is always `[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]`.

On converting to categories, it always results in fifty.

My dataset contains almost 2200 images with an average of 350-500 images for each class.

Can someone help out with this..?

Comment: Please, show the code that you are using to save the model.

Comment: Also, include model.summary() output.

Comment: Include you tensorflow vension to, since tensorflow 2.x have new ways to save a model.

Comment: I have added the code which I used to save the model @FelipeBorges.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice @furcifer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that when you train, you normalize your images:

```
X = X/255.0
```

but when you test, i.e., in prediction time, you just read your image and resize but not normalize. Try:

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE=100
    img_array=cv2.imread(filepath)
    img_array = img_array/255.0
    new_array=cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
```

and also, your `prepare` function returns your image in 4 dimensions (including the batch dimension), so when you call `predict`, you do not have to give the input as a list. Instead of:

```
prediction=model.predict([prepare('30.jpg')])
```

you should do:

```
prediction=model.predict(prepare('30.jpg'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey  Bashir. Thank you for your guidance, but in testing process, denormalization is not possible right..? I tried normalizing but it results in exponent values. The predict parameter passing tip was useful though. Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome. I do not understand what you mean by denormalization and exponent values. Using the prepare function I wrote, could you share the result of your prediction?

Comment: Sure Bashir. I got the following output for the updated prepare function.    [[2.9802322e-07 0.0000000e+00 1.2387794e-01 2.9504299e-06 9.5416647e-07]]. Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be as expected. Those are the probabilities for each category. calling `prediction = np.argmax(prediction, -1)` would give you the actual category. It gives you the index, hence the category, with the highest probability.

Comment: Thank you so much Bashir. It works out fine now. Seriously thanks man for your timely guidance.

Comment: So the problem earlier was with Normalization..? Or is there something more that you have changed or updated...? I am new to Deep Learning. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem Ram, the problem was certainly with the normalization. You are training your model to classify images that have pixel values in the range (0, 1), but when you predict, you are asking it to classify unnormalized image (with pixels in the range (0, 255)). so the model does not understand it. You have to give similar images at training and test/prediction time to your model, otherwise it won't work.. If it solves your problem, please accept my answer (Mark it as accepted).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the solution to the error in detail Bashir. I understand the problem now. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help :)